# the difference between "few" and "little"

Tags: word-usage

in wiring and conversation I have confused to use the correct words from "little" and "few" how to use the words little and few in english writing and conversation

Answer (score 2):

"Few" means "a small number", so it refers to things you can *count*. For example, you might say there are "few people at the event" or "a few cars in the parking lot".

"Little" means "a small quantity" or "not very much" of something, so it refers to non-countable substances. For example, you could have "a little water", or "little conversation".

Answer (score 0):

Here an example:

> "There are few students at the school after the evening because the class was canceled."
>
> "I have little time after coming back home from work, so I need to rest."

As said, "few" is for **countable** things, but "little" is not.

Comment: your answers are helpful, thank you all